# How to create an instance of HttpPostedFileBase(or its inherited type)

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

Currently I have a `byte[]` that contains all the data of an image file, just want to build an instance of `HttpPostedFileBase` so that I can use an existing method, instead of creating a new overload one.

```
public ActionResult Save(HttpPostedFileBase file)

public ActionResult Save(byte[] data)
{
    //Hope I can construct an instance of HttpPostedFileBase here and then
    return Save(file);

    //instead of writing a lot of similar codes
}
```

Comment: did you get the answer to work for parsing the file stored in the byte[] ? Mine keeps the content disposition, etc.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Create a derived class as follows:

```
class MemoryFile : HttpPostedFileBase
{
Stream stream;
string contentType;
string fileName;

public MemoryFile(Stream stream, string contentType, string fileName)
{
    this.stream = stream;
    this.contentType = contentType;
    this.fileName = fileName;
}

public override int ContentLength
{
    get { return (int)stream.Length; }
}

public override string ContentType
{
    get { return contentType; }
}

public override string FileName
{
    get { return fileName; }
}

public override Stream InputStream
{
    get { return stream; }
}

public override void SaveAs(string filename)
{
    using (var file = File.Open(filename, FileMode.CreateNew))
        stream.CopyTo(file);
}
}
```

Now you can pass instance of this class where HttpPostedFileBase is expected.

Comment: Just wanted to show how to use MemoryFile after you created: `string filePath = Path.GetFullPath("C:\\images.rar");
            FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open);
            MemoryFile fileImage = new MemoryFile(fileStream, "application/x-rar-compressed", "images.rar");`

Comment: Tu es un genie! You, sir, are a genius!

Comment: Just remember to close/dispose of that `fileStream` when you have finished otherwise you will leave the file permanently open (and inaccessible).

Answer (score 1):

You cannot manually create an instance of `HttpPostedFileBase` or derived classes (`HttpPostedFile`). This class is only supposed to be instantiated by the framework. Why don't you get rid of the second controller action that takes a byte array? It's not necessary. The default model binder will work fine with the one taking a `HttpPostedFileBase`.

Comment: The js developer post me the byte[], this issue happens when user is pasting an image from the clipboard, instead of selecting an image file to upload.

Comment: @Danny Chen, js sending a `byte[]`? That's seems very weird. What protocol is being used?

Comment: He is sending me a base64 string, this behavior is performed by a 3rd party js editor.